# Google APIs vs Google Play Services, Why we need Google APIs now?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-api, google-play-services

We used to use Google APIs SDK to use functionality like Google Maps, which is now available in Google Play Services Library.

So do we still need to create our android project with Google APIs, or can use simply android?

[image: Select Google APIs or just Android 4.2.2?]

Comment: you need google api's and get the key for connecting to the google servers such as for google maps v3

Comment: isn't the latest native maps API is v2 and not v3?
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/

Also I guess its part of Play Services? no really get what you mean here.

Comment: ya sorry i mentioned about the javascript version. you can use simply any android version i have used it and it's working fine. however you will need to import the `google play services library` and include it.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using maps v2 then no you do not need google API's you just need to import google play services

Comment: Then why there is a Google APIs SDK available to download?

Comment: google api's is not just maps there are other things in the API too (most if not all are deprecated) but in order to use all the new stuff you need google play services which all devices do not have. so if you made an app and want it to work on a device that does not have the play store then you are stuck using the old google api's